# Exporting multiple tables into separate Excel tabs

Tags: asp.net, export-to-excel

We have two different tables.

Tables: `Category`, `Product`

Now we need to import the `Category` table data in `Sheet 1` of Excel file and `Product` details in `Sheet 2`.

Is there any reference is there?

Answer (score 1):

You may use [EasyXLS](http://www.easyxls.com) Excel library.

Use this code to insert the tables data in multiple sheets:

```
DataSet dataSetCategory = ...//extract Category table details from database
DataSet dataSetProduct = ...//extract Product table details from database

//Create an Excel file having two sheets
ExcelDocument xls = new ExcelDocument(2);

//Get the sheets
ExcelWorksheet xlsSheet1 = (ExcelWorksheet)xls.easy_getSheetAt(1);
ExcelWorksheet xlsSheet2 = (ExcelWorksheet)xls.easy_getSheetAt(2);

//Insert the datasets
xlsSheet1.easy_insertDataSet(dataSetCategory, 
                         new ExcelAutoFormat(Styles.AUTOFORMAT_EASYXLS1), true);
xlsSheet2.easy_insertDataSet(dataSetProduct, 
                         new ExcelAutoFormat(Styles.AUTOFORMAT_EASYXLS1), true);

//Export the Excel file
xls.easy_WriteXLSFile(fileStream);
or 
xls.easy_WriteXLSXFile(fileStream);
```

Probably you want to open the file from the browser, so you can write the Excel file into the ResponseStream and add this extra code.

```
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=YourFile.xls"); 
Response.ContentType = "application/octetstream";
Response.Clear();

//Generate the file and prompt the "Open or Save Dialog Box" 
xls.easy_WriteXLSFile(Response.OutputStream);
```

If you need more details about how to import the dataset, you can check this link:

[How to export dataset to Excel in C#](http://www.easyxls.com/manual/basics/export-dataset-to-excel.html)